# Should I submit a tax declaration if I've been working in USA only about 30 days in total?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-resident

For a while I've been working and living in USA (and paying taxes of course) as a L1 visa holder. In February 2017 - I've left the job (so L1-based work permission is invalidated), left the country after I've declared my taxes for 2016.

My question would be - should I somehow file my tax declaration again, basically for January'17 and literally for a couple of days in February?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would ...... get all the money back, right?  So probably yeah!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a tax *declaration* in US tax law; the declaration is part of the tax *return* which you need to file for the income that you earned in January and February of 2017 -- this income tax return for 2017 is due by mid-April 2018.  It might be that you are not *required* to file the income tax return at all if your income is small enough, though I am not sure if this rule applies to non-residents on L-1 visas. But, given that you worked for only thirty days, you may well be entitled to a *refund* of *withheld* income tax because too much was withheld, and you *must* file a tax return to *claim* the refund even though you are not *required* to file a tax return on the grounds of low income; you don't automatically get a refund of over-withheld tax.